# php glob not matching any files in directory

Tags: php

I am trying to display random images from a directory, but `glob` keeps giving me this error:

```
Undefined offset: 0
```

Which leads me to believe that it is not matching the `.png` files. However shouldn't it match all files in the directory? Thanks

Code:

```
$banners = glob("/lib/theme/ivao/images/banners/*");
$img1 = $banners[rand(0,count($banners)-1)];
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with this. what version of PHP are you using? check for errors too, Use error reporting.

Comment: I have simply numbered the image files and used rand in the img tag to get er done. I am stumped

Comment: you didn't answer my question. what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I am using native 5.4

Comment: ok well we know it's not because of that. Either try a relative path instead of a full system path, and/or check if the folder(s) / file(s) permissions as stated in the comments below. Check your path and use error reporting to see if it returns any other errors, if you're not already doing so. Here's a link for it http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: make sure the path is correct `/lib/theme/ivao/images/banners/` - it may even be something like  `/var/home/htdocs/lib/theme/ivao/images/banners/`

Comment: Yes, I also think it is a problem of path or permissions (for add permission to list the files in a directory, see the comments in answer below).

Comment: @mlpo folders are usually 755 and files 644, that's what I always used

Comment: could it have something to do with the line in my .htaccess that ignores indexes??

Answer (score 0):

`$banners` is empty. So when you try to access an item, PHP returns an error.

To avoid this kinds of mistakes, do not hesitate to show your array with `var_dump` or `print_r` for example:

```
$banners = glob("/lib/theme/ivao/images/banners/*");
var_dump($banners);
```

Several reasons may explain why `glob` returns an empty array: PHP can perhaps not access to the directory or it may be empty or does not exist.

Comment: Im a noob when it comes to file permissions, is it possible for me to access them in an img tag but not in glob?? I doubt it

Comment: It all depends on the user running the script. Here it is possible to add permission to access the directory and list files to all users with `chmod a+x /lib/theme/ivao/images/banners/` (it may be necessary to use `sudo` to change the permissions on this directory).